# Reset table cell color when one of the cells is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I have a user survey with a list of questions and five likert radio  onclick="setRadio(this, 'row_1')"objects for each.  Each question is on its own row in a table.  When a user clicks one of the likert cells, it hightlights that cell in yellow.  The problem is that the other cells on the same row aren't being reset, so if they change their selection, we now have two yellow cells.

I'd like to reset all cells on the row to the default colors, however I'm having trouble making this work.

```
<table>
<tr id='row_1'>
<td>The sky is blue</td>
<td><input name="sqid_1" type=radio  onclick="setRadio(this, 'row_1')" name='lid_1' value=1> Strongly disagree</td>
<td><input name="sqid_1" type=radio  onclick="setRadio(this, 'row_1')" name='lid_1' value=2> Disagree</td>
<td><input name="sqid_1" type=radio  onclick="setRadio(this, 'row_1')" name='lid_1' value=3> Neutral</td>
<td><input name="sqid_1" type=radio  onclick="setRadio(this, 'row_1')" name='lid_1' value=4> Agree</td>
<td><input name="sqid_1" type=radio  onclick="setRadio(this, 'row_1')" name='lid_1' value=5> Strongly agree</td>
</tr>
<tr id='row_2'>
<td>The sky is green</td>
<td><input name="sqid_2" type=radio  onclick="setRadio(this, 'row_2')" name='lid_1' value=1> Strongly disagree</td>
<td><input name="sqid_2" type=radio  onclick="setRadio(this, 'row_2')" name='lid_2' value=2> Disagree</td>
<td><input name="sqid_2" type=radio  onclick="setRadio(this, 'row_2')" name='lid_3' value=3> Neutral</td>
<td><input name="sqid_2" type=radio  onclick="setRadio(this, 'row_2')" name='lid_4' value=4> Agree</td>
<td><input name="sqid_2" type=radio  onclick="setRadio(this, 'row_1')" name='lid_5' value=5> Strongly agree</td>
</tr>

<!-- lots more rows of questions & likert scales here -->
</table>
```

The basic javascript

```
        <script language='javascript'>
            function setRadio(oTD, row_id) 
            {

                document.getElementById(row_id).style.color ='';
                var el, i = 0;
                while (el = oTD.childNodes[i++]) 
                {
                    if (el.type == 'radio')
                    {
                        el.checked = true;
                        el.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
```

That sets the background color to yellow, but the row color reset is not working as intended (the previously selected cells on the same row remain yellow).

Is there a better, hopefully painless way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Can't solve your issue in full now, but you'd want a jquery function selecting all tags with name 'td'. So your function would look like: $('td').click(function() {....});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use a library for that. Here's how to do it with some small native Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>    
<body>
    <form action="whatever">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>The sky is blue</td>
                <td class="likertCells">
                    <input type="radio" name='lid_1' value="1">Strongly disagree</td>
                <td class="likertCells">
                    <input type="radio" name='lid_1' value="2">Disagree</td>
                <td class="likertCells">
                    <input type="radio" name='lid_1' value="3">Neutral</td>
                <td class="likertCells">
                    <input type="radio" name='lid_1' value="4">Agree</td>
                <td class="likertCells">
                    <input type="radio" name='lid_1' value="5">Strongly agree</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>The sky is green</td>
                <td class="likertCells">
                    <input type="radio" name='lid_2' value="1">Strongly disagree</td>
                <td class="likertCells">
                    <input type="radio" name='lid_2' value="2">Disagree</td>
                <td class="likertCells">
                    <input type="radio" name='lid_2' value="3">Neutral</td>
                <td class="likertCells">
                    <input type="radio" name='lid_2' value="4">Agree</td>
                <td class="likertCells">
                    <input type="radio" name='lid_2' value="5">Strongly agree</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <script>
        var likertCells = document.querySelectorAll('.likertCells'); // Mind the dot!
        for (var i = 0; i < likertCells.length; i++) {
            likertCells[i].setAttribute('onclick', 'checkRadioAndHighlight(this)')
        }

        function checkRadioAndHighlight(caller) {
            var theKids = caller.childNodes;
            for (var j = 0; j < theKids.length; j++) {
                if (theKids[j].type == 'radio') theKids[j].checked = true;
            }
            var theSiblings = caller.parentNode.childNodes;
            for (var k = 0; k < theSiblings.length; k++) {
                if (theSiblings[k].tagName == 'TD') // The DOM returns tagNames in uppercase!
                theSiblings[k].style.backgroundColor = '';
            }
            caller.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFBF';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

.

Checked in IE8/9, Chrome30 and FF28. You gave the radios two names each, so I deleted one. But as their names don't play a role in the Javascript, you can replace the one I left in place. Just make sure to make the other name an Id, not a second name.

Comment: So what this is doing is highlighting the entire row yellow when I select one of the radios.  EDIT.  It looks like yours works as expected in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/73gAb/

Comment: Spotted our difference.  I have some code to allow a radio object to be selected by clicking the cell. Here's the fiddle of what I'm seeing: http://jsfiddle.net/EfvwL/

Comment: if you'll update your answer so that it better addresses my question (clicking a cell, not a radio object) I'll select yours as correct answer.

Comment: @acoder - I missed that, that you wanted the cell to be the caller. Updated the answer. As you can see, I separated the content and the JS, while the code is still intuitive. I hope you like it. Here is the demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wczKj?editors=100.

Comment: Your solution is a little different from mine  (http://jsfiddle.net/335tr/) but it works just the same - thank you.

Comment: @acoder - You're welcome. But you should keep the content code as (c)lean as possible. For reasons of readability, and in case of dynamically generated content it makes the back-end coding much easier.

Comment: @acoder - At the major update, I used `getElementsByClassName(class)`, but to make it function in IE8 as well, that had to be changed to `querySelectorAll(.class)`. Mind the dot, and note that the demo has not been updated due to lack of time. The code in the answer has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

Are you open to jQuery?

```
$(function(){
    $("td input").parent().click(function(){
        $(this).css("background", "yellow").siblings("td").css("background", "white");
    });
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6hPx/)

Note that the `.parent()` used here is to prevent this being applied to the title column. It selects only `<td>` elements with `<input>`s in them

Comment: jQuery is fine, will check out the solution tomorrow. thanks.